Azure Application Gateway for Containers Throws 403 On Websocket Connection
We have a new Kubernetes stack on Azure, with ingresses set up and an Application Gateway for Containers, normal HTTP/HTTPS traffic seems to flow perfectly fine, but our websockets over WSS are all getting 403s.

The application works fine on AWS (in a ton of other environments, with load balancers, without, etc.)
When logging on our application as part of our websocket auth code, we never see the request come in (but we do see all the other requests being made), suggesting we never make it by the AGC
I see practically no configuration on the AGC though, nor do I see any ingress configuration that would suggest fixing WSS
Certs are fine, chain is good, etc.


According to Azure support, websockets are currently not yet supported by AGC. It seems to be on the roadmap, no ETA though.
